# How can I load text from a .jl file and display it into a webpage?

Tags: html, julia

I want to build a single page website that I can search for an item within a .jl file. For example, if I search "shoes" then all shoe items from the .jl file should appear.

I've tried looking into converting the .jl file into JSON but I don't know how to.

Comment: So all you want to do is parse a .jl file and look for a specific word/phrase?

Comment: correct! that's exactly what i need

Comment: I still don't quite understand - do you need the julia code to actually run, and search the outputs, or you just want to see if the word `shoes` appears somewhere in the raw code?

Comment: I need the term "shoes" to appear in the raw code and then display it in a web page

Comment: Not sure I understand what you’re trying to do either. Mind reformatting the question to be a little more clear what you’re going after and how specifically you are trying to use Julia?

Comment: What do you mean by ".jl" file? What format does it use? ".jl" is just a file extension, not a format, and is used by at least Julia files and JSON Lines / ndjson. Voting to close as unclear.

Answer (score -2):

Surely you could make them all functions, and if they search ' shoes ' then a shoe function is called and it displays it.

But if it's a large file, then I guess it wouldn't work.

Comment: it's a very big file, 93mb of just text